# how to sort string datewise?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In my grid view there is column which contain with string data type. Some date field and some string constants  are filled in that column.I want sorting of this column by dates not by alphabets.

Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Can we have the column content for example

Comment: Yes for sure 05/21/2009,07/11/2010,Open,11/02/2011,Closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your datasource is SQL, you could use the following `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY NULLIF(ISDATE([DateColumn]), 0)
```

This will convert all none date values, to `NULL`, and order by date

Comment: Thanks for sharing but i needed to check it in the Rowbound event of the gridview.